# APIs for returning a geoJSON circle shape file for a post request that contains a lat/long centerpoint

Tags: geolocation, geospatial, geojson

Does anyone have suggestions regarding APIs available (free and paid) for posting a lat/long and the API returning a geoJSON shape file built from the lat/long posted?

For example, if I want to a shapefile of a 50 meter circle, derived from a lat/long 42.38567/-86.26877 CenterPoint, are there APIs that can do that? I have 24,000 locations I need this for, and I would very much like not to hand draw 24K polygons on a map.

I've investigated turf.js and developer.here.com but the documentation has been pretty unclear on what endpoint to post to, to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Most geographical libraries have `buffer` method, meaning they can do it locally (you don't even need any external API).

E.g. geopandas has `buffer(distance, resolution)` method - distance controls the radius, and resolution tells how precise the circle has to be. You construct point, call `buffer` method - get circle (approximated as polygon) as output.

Or you can load these points to a database with geospatial functionality (say, PostgreSQL + PostGIS) and call `ST_Buffer` method to do the same.